# Distinguishing between two "symmetrical" arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of values of angles in radians. The two arrays are symmetrical with respect to a known constant angle. The arrays are shown in the figure:
[image: Array values in blue and red]

The example values are following:

```
   one = [ 2.98153965 -1.33298928  2.94993567 -1.39909924  2.99214403  3.00138863
  3.04390642 -1.59098448 -1.65660299 -1.73146174 -1.8166248  -2.85595599
 -2.02035274 -2.64530394 -2.26451127 -2.3982946  -2.52735954 -2.17570346
 -2.77544658 -2.88566686 -1.84913768 -3.07261908 -1.66738719 -1.6029932
 -1.54596053 -1.50177363 -1.46133745 -1.42288915 -1.38241718  2.79925996
 -1.30775884 -1.27309395  2.72153718 -1.20592812 -1.18113435 -1.15029987]

two = [-1.30507254  2.9385436  -1.36415496  2.95897805 -1.43845065 -1.48295087
 -1.53346541  3.09685482 -3.11358085 -3.0466034  -2.95794156 -1.9128659
 -2.75067133 -2.13826992 -2.51567194 -2.39565127 -2.28148844 -2.65519436
 -2.05312249 -1.95523663 -2.98473857 -1.75415233  3.13322155  3.06539723
  3.00595703  2.95378704  2.90786779  2.86730208  2.831318   -1.34113191
  2.77057495  2.74479777 -1.23620286  2.70046364  2.68129889  2.66380717]
```

It can be seen that the values are "following" two symmetrical arctan lines, my question is how do I distinguish between the two of them, and get something like this:
[image: Distinguished arrays]

I've tried several approaches but can't come up with a universal one which will work in all cases, there is often a misinterpreted section assigned to the wrong array.

Any ideas are welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary that they be kept separate? It looks like the values are simply split across the two arrays. Why not merge them into one array?

Comment: The plots you show don't seem to be exactly symmetrical... Otherwise you can use the mirror symmetry around the intersection point to separate the arrays. Hint: the derivatives are of opposite signs for the cross section at y=const. If the function is monotonous you just need the three values around the intersection point.

Comment: @erapert - They're not, each of the two arrays in the first graph has values for the whole range from 0 to 35.

Comment: _The two arrays are symmetrical with respect to a known constant angle_ (so it should be given, assumed as given) and _values of angles in radians_ seem to be valuable information - 'phase un-wrapping' will only be by int * _pi_  Will the unwrapped data ever span more than one  2 *_pi_  interval?

Comment: The wrapped data is produced by an algorithm which always wraps it into the [-pi, pi) range. When unwrapped, it will only span one 2*pi interval, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty come from the 2 pi jump, which can be resolved by :

```
def transform(x):
    return x+2*pi*(x<0)
```

This function transform the arrays in *continuous* ones. You must first turn your lists in ndarrays.

then :

```
t=arange(one.size)    
tone = transform(one)
ttwo = transform(two)

maxi=np.maximum(tone,ttwo)
subplot(211)
plot(t,tone,'o',t,ttwo,'o',maxi)
```

induces what to do :

```
i=maxi.argmin()
dicrease = np.choose(np.logical_xor(tone>ttwo,t<i),[tone,ttwo])
increase = np.choose(np.logical_xor(tone>ttwo,t<i),[ttwo,tone])
subplot(212)
plot(t,dicrease,label='dicrease')
plot(t,increase,label='increase')
legend()
```

for

[image]

You can if necessary turn back in `[-pi,pi[` by `x -> (x + pi) % (2*pi) - pi` .

**EDIT**

for a less ad hoc transform, I propose this other, which will probably solve more cases :

```
def transform2(y,gap):
    breaks=np.diff(y)**2>gap**2/2
    signs=np.sign(np.diff(y))
    offset=np.concatenate(([0],(breaks*signs).cumsum()))*gap
    return y-offset
```

and an noisy example :
[image]

Comment: This works, for some cases, like some of the other approaches I made. There are cases in which all the values are > 0 after "continualisation" you proposed, but the functions are still not continuous. Like [here](https://imgur.com/a/fXRMo).

Still, thanks for the idea, I suppose I need to find all the intersections, or close points between top and bottom line, kind of what I've been trying to use from the beginning, but always with an error or two...

Comment: mmmh... let me think to a more robust transform.

Comment: I propose a other transform. say me if it improves the process.

Comment: Not really sure how I should set the gap parameter, but I guess it's quite hard for anyone to help without having all the different datasets. I guess I will end up tweaking and combining all the proposed solutions.
P.S. The ''noise'' in my case comes from the estimation error, which is huge, so it easily crosses between the two desired symmetrical lines.

Comment: gap is `2pi` in your case. I understood it was a mathematical artifact, not subject to noise, so not so difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that minimizes the distance between consecutive points and also the change in slope (weighted by parameter `lam`). Distance alone fails at the crossover point. [image]

```
import numpy as np

one = list(map(float, """ 2.98153965 -1.33298928  2.94993567 -1.39909924  2.99214403  3.00138863
  3.04390642 -1.59098448 -1.65660299 -1.73146174 -1.8166248  -2.85595599
 -2.02035274 -2.64530394 -2.26451127 -2.3982946  -2.52735954 -2.17570346
 -2.77544658 -2.88566686 -1.84913768 -3.07261908 -1.66738719 -1.6029932
 -1.54596053 -1.50177363 -1.46133745 -1.42288915 -1.38241718  2.79925996
 -1.30775884 -1.27309395  2.72153718 -1.20592812 -1.18113435 -1.15029987""".split()))

two = list(map(float, """-1.30507254  2.9385436  -1.36415496  2.95897805 -1.43845065 -1.48295087
 -1.53346541  3.09685482 -3.11358085 -3.0466034  -2.95794156 -1.9128659
 -2.75067133 -2.13826992 -2.51567194 -2.39565127 -2.28148844 -2.65519436
 -2.05312249 -1.95523663 -2.98473857 -1.75415233  3.13322155  3.06539723
  3.00595703  2.95378704  2.90786779  2.86730208  2.831318   -1.34113191
  2.77057495  2.74479777 -1.23620286  2.70046364  2.68129889  2.66380717""".split()))

data = np.array([one, two])

dd = (data[[[0, 1], [1, 0]], 1:] - data[:, None, :-1] + np.pi)%(2*np.pi) - np.pi
dde2 = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk', dd, dd)

xovr1 = np.argmin(dde2, axis=0)
pick1 = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(xovr1) & 1]

d2d = dd[:, :, None, 1:] - dd[[[1, 0], [0, 1]], :, :-1]
d2de2 = np.r_['2', np.zeros((2, 2, 1)), np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->jkl', d2d, d2d)]

lam = 0.5
e2 = (dde2[:, None, :] + lam * d2de2).reshape(4, -1)

xovr2 = np.argmin(e2, axis=0)>>1
pick2 = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(xovr2) & 1]

print('by position only')
print(data[pick1, np.arange(data.shape[1])])
print(data[1-pick1, np.arange(data.shape[1])])

print('by position and slope')
print(data[pick2, np.arange(data.shape[1])])
print(data[1-pick2, np.arange(data.shape[1])])


# by position only
# [ 2.98153965  2.9385436   2.94993567  2.95897805  2.99214403  3.00138863
#   3.04390642  3.09685482 -3.11358085 -3.0466034  -2.95794156 -2.85595599
#  -2.75067133 -2.64530394 -2.51567194 -2.3982946  -2.52735954 -2.65519436
#  -2.77544658 -2.88566686 -2.98473857 -3.07261908  3.13322155  3.06539723
#   3.00595703  2.95378704  2.90786779  2.86730208  2.831318    2.79925996
#   2.77057495  2.74479777  2.72153718  2.70046364  2.68129889  2.66380717]
# [-1.30507254 -1.33298928 -1.36415496 -1.39909924 -1.43845065 -1.48295087
#  -1.53346541 -1.59098448 -1.65660299 -1.73146174 -1.8166248  -1.9128659
#  -2.02035274 -2.13826992 -2.26451127 -2.39565127 -2.28148844 -2.17570346
#  -2.05312249 -1.95523663 -1.84913768 -1.75415233 -1.66738719 -1.6029932
#  -1.54596053 -1.50177363 -1.46133745 -1.42288915 -1.38241718 -1.34113191
#  -1.30775884 -1.27309395 -1.23620286 -1.20592812 -1.18113435 -1.15029987]
# by position and slope
# [ 2.98153965  2.9385436   2.94993567  2.95897805  2.99214403  3.00138863
#   3.04390642  3.09685482 -3.11358085 -3.0466034  -2.95794156 -2.85595599
#  -2.75067133 -2.64530394 -2.51567194 -2.39565127 -2.28148844 -2.17570346
#  -2.05312249 -1.95523663 -1.84913768 -1.75415233 -1.66738719 -1.6029932
#  -1.54596053 -1.50177363 -1.46133745 -1.42288915 -1.38241718 -1.34113191
#  -1.30775884 -1.27309395 -1.23620286 -1.20592812 -1.18113435 -1.15029987]
# [-1.30507254 -1.33298928 -1.36415496 -1.39909924 -1.43845065 -1.48295087
#  -1.53346541 -1.59098448 -1.65660299 -1.73146174 -1.8166248  -1.9128659
#  -2.02035274 -2.13826992 -2.26451127 -2.3982946  -2.52735954 -2.65519436
#  -2.77544658 -2.88566686 -2.98473857 -3.07261908  3.13322155  3.06539723
#   3.00595703  2.95378704  2.90786779  2.86730208  2.831318    2.79925996
#   2.77057495  2.74479777  2.72153718  2.70046364  2.68129889  2.66380717]
```

Comment: I guess this would be the right answer, haven't refreshed the page before posting my "answer". I'll test it on more cases, but if it covers both cases as you say, it should work. And is far more formal than mine, without the 0.8 tweaking. Thanks!

Comment: Tried on various datasets, shows the same weaknesses as my previous attempts, [example](https://imgur.com/a/A6iTf)

Comment: Could you try cranking up `lam`? This will increase the penalty for cusps. With the one data set you shared I can put `lam` at 100 without breaking things.

Comment: Will give this a go in the next couple of days and follow up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works, and covers for both cases, when the `maxi` and `mini` functions meet, and when there is a "jump". Still, there is a constant which needs adjusting (in my case 0.8) to cover for the slight variations in mini or maxi.

```
one = one + 2*np.pi*(one < 0)
two = two + 2*np.pi*(two < 0)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title(run)

t = np.arange(one.size)

maxi = np.maximum(one, two)
mini = np.minimum(one, two)

breaks = np.array([0])
ct = 0

first = np.array([])
second = np.array([])

ch = [maxi, mini]

for i in range(1, maxi.size):
    if maxi[i] < mini[i-1] or mini[i] > maxi[i-1]:
        breaks = np.append(breaks, [i])
        ct += 1
        first = np.append(first, ch[0][breaks[ct-1]:breaks[ct]])
        second = np.append(second, ch[1][breaks[ct-1]:breaks[ct]])
        ch = ch[::-1]
    elif i != maxi.size-1:
        if maxi[i] - mini[i] < 0.8*min(maxi[i-1] - mini[i-1], maxi[i+1] - mini[i+1]):
            breaks = np.append(breaks, [i])
            ct += 1
            first = np.append(first, ch[0][breaks[ct - 1]:breaks[ct]])
            second = np.append(second, ch[1][breaks[ct - 1]:breaks[ct]])
            ch = ch[::-1]

first = np.append(first, ch[0][breaks[ct]:])
second = np.append(second, ch[1][breaks[ct]:])

plt.plot(maxi, 'r.', label='maxi')
plt.plot(mini, 'b.', label='mini')
plt.plot(first, label='first')
plt.plot(second, label='second')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 8})
plt.show()
```

So it ends up looking like this:[image]

or this:[image]

These were the true value datasets, it is only going to start being fun when I start using the noisy outputs from an estimation algorithm.